# C++ - How to iterate through all of the combinations of an array for bruteforcing

Tags: c++, arrays, brute-force

I have a exercise finding all of the possible sums of 1-9 that add up to 100, the rules are that each number has to be used once and in order and the operators allowed are +/- and adding the digits together eg. 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9 = 100

I have written the logic for figuring it out already, I have an array of 9 elements that represent all of the positions where an operator can be placed, 1 being +, 2 being -, and 3 adding the digits together.
the operator string for the example above would be {1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,1}.

So my real question is how can I iterate through this operator array and generate every single possible combination of numbers.

so I start with
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

and progress through like so until the array is all 3s

```
111111111
111111112
111111113
111111121
111111122
111111123
111111131
```

I had written a function for this around last year but it used a lot of if else statements making the function not flexible, I would like suggestions on what is the correct procedure on doing this since I'd like to improve my coding.

Comment: how do you generate the list of combinations of numbers? You can do the same to get all combinations of operators

Comment: and please show what you tried. Include a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: You have 9 digits (1, 2, ..., 9) and an operation between each pair of digit -> 8 positions. The operations are `+`, `-`, `cat()` where `cat()` makes a number of left and right argument. That may sound difficult actually it's just something which does `l * 10 + r`. Based on this, you can to iterate the first of these 8 operators over the 3 operations, then inc. the 2nd, iterate the first again, then inc. the 2nd, etc. (The principle is like an [Odometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometer) but 8 nested loops may achieve the same effect.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP was so fair to state that the question is about homework

> I have a exercise finding all of the possible sums of 1-9 that add up to 100

So, I don't present a full solution of this exercise but something where not so much has to be added to achieve this.

There are nine arguments given (the digits 1 … 9) which are arguments of binary operators.

A binary operator requires a left and a right argument. Hence, I conclude there are 8 positions to choose a binary operator.

That's quite easy for `+` and `-` but what about *adding the digits*?

This is an operation I would call "concatenate". Actually, it's easy to express "concatenate" as simple arithmetic expression:

```
lr: 10 * l + r
```

After the "concatenation" issue is solved, this is not anymore so complicated.

My first idea was to use something like functors or function pointers but it's not too hard to solve it without.

For this, I define an enumeration of operations:

```
enum Op { Add, Sub, Cat, NOps};
```

and a `compute()` function for these operations:

```
int compute(Op op, int l, int r)
{
  switch (op) {
    case Add: return l + r;
    case Sub: return l - r;
    case Cat: return l * 10 + r;
  }
  // ...unreachable for the humans eyes but not for the compiler...
  assert(false); return 0;
}
```

The next puzzle piece is a function which computes the result for a complete equation.
The equation is defined by N arguments (the digits) and N - 1 operators.

While implementing this, I realized that the "concatenation" has to have a higher precedence. Otherwise, the compute function would not work properly.

Example:

```
12 + 23 = 35
```

Without considering the higher precedence of "concatenation", this would result in:

```
12 + 23 = ((12) + 2)3 = (14)3 = 143
```

For a simple solution of this issue, the compute function should make two runs:

1. to resolve all concatenations
2. to resolve all other operations.

```
int compute(std::vector<int> args, std::vector<Op> &ops)
{
  assert(args.size() == ops.size() + 1);
  // perform cat()
  std::vector<int> args2;
  args2.push_back(args[0]);
  for (size_t i = 0, n = ops.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    if (ops[i] == Cat) {
      int l = args2.back(); args2.pop_back();
      args2.push_back(compute(Cat, l, args[i + 1]));
    } else args2.push_back(args[i + 1]);
  }
  // perform add() and sub()
  int result = args2[0];
  for (size_t i = 0, j = 1, n = ops.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    const Op op = ops[i];
    if (op != Cat) result = compute(op, result, args2[j++]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The last missing piece is an [Odometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometer)-like iteration of the values in `std::vector<Op> &ops`. The simplest way (though not the most elegant) are a respective amount of nested `for` loops.

So, here we are:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum Op { Add, Sub, Cat, NOps};

int compute(Op op, int l, int r)
{
  switch (op) {
    case Add: return l + r;
    case Sub: return l - r;
    case Cat: return l * 10 + r;
  }
  // ...unreachable for the humans eyes but not for the compiler...
  assert(false); return 0;
}

/* Attention!
 * cat() must have higher precedence then add() and sub()
 */

int compute(std::vector<int> args, std::vector<Op> &ops)
{
  assert(args.size() == ops.size() + 1);
  // perform cat()
  std::vector<int> args2;
  args2.push_back(args[0]);
  for (size_t i = 0, n = ops.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    if (ops[i] == Cat) {
      int l = args2.back(); args2.pop_back();
      args2.push_back(compute(Cat, l, args[i + 1]));
    } else args2.push_back(args[i + 1]);
  }
  // perform add() and sub()
  int result = args2[0];
  for (size_t i = 0, j = 1, n = ops.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    const Op op = ops[i];
    if (op != Cat) result = compute(op, result, args2[j++]);
  }
  return result;
}

const char* toString(Op op)
{
  static const char* texts[] = { " + ", " - ", "" };
  return texts[op];
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> args = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  std::vector<Op> ops(args.size() - 1);
  for (int op2 = 0; op2 < NOps; ++op2) {
    ops[2] = (Op)op2;
    for (int op1 = 0; op1 < NOps; ++op1) {
      ops[1] = (Op)op1;
      for (int op0 = 0; op0 < NOps; ++op0) {
        ops[0] = (Op)op0;
        // print equation
        std::cout << args[0];
        for (size_t i = 0, n = ops.size(); i < n; ++i) {
          std::cout << toString(ops[i]) << args[i + 1];
        }
        std::cout << " = " << compute(args, ops) << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
1 - 2 + 3 + 4 = 6
12 + 3 + 4 = 19
1 + 2 - 3 + 4 = 4
1 - 2 - 3 + 4 = 0
12 - 3 + 4 = 13
1 + 23 + 4 = 28
1 - 23 + 4 = -18
123 + 4 = 127
1 + 2 + 3 - 4 = 2
1 - 2 + 3 - 4 = -2
12 + 3 - 4 = 11
1 + 2 - 3 - 4 = -4
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 = -8
12 - 3 - 4 = 5
1 + 23 - 4 = 20
1 - 23 - 4 = -26
123 - 4 = 119
1 + 2 + 34 = 37
1 - 2 + 34 = 33
12 + 34 = 46
1 + 2 - 34 = -31
1 - 2 - 34 = -35
12 - 34 = -22
1 + 234 = 235
1 - 234 = -233
1234 = 1234
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/923404224d67139e)

**Note:**

I used only 4 instead of 9 digits because I believe this is enough to show the principle and should be easy enough to extend by the OP (as well as to add the test of the computed result to be acceptable or not).

Comment: I originally came to the same conclusion with doing a concat for when needed but when I came to the issue of precedence I decided to work through generating a string with the sum first and then parsing through the sum and performing a calculation and see if the result is valid. the only issue I had was the odometer part as I knew it in concept but I couldn't visualize how to make it work until you mentioned an odometer style of counting, I have written a generic odometer function that I can plug into my existing solution. Thank you very much, I hope my C++ is good as yours one day (student rn)

Comment: The issue of precedence could be solved as well by comparing left and right operator of the inner arguments, and solve the one with higher first. (This has to be repeated in case.) I must admit I was too lazy to think this way upto end... ;-) And, thanks for the flowers though I surely have written C++ code I'm even more proud of.